# "gamecenter undefined" using a Game Center Cordova plugin

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

What am i doing wrong? I have set up Game Center in Xcode and iTunes connect, but yet in Javascript... I get an error saying `gamecenter is not defined` when I try to authenticate the user.

PLUGIN: https://github.com/leecrossley/cordova-plugin-game-center

```
var successCallback = function (user) {
    alert(user.alias);
    // user.alias, user.playerID, user.displayName
};

gamecenter.auth(successCallback, failureCallback);
```

My full JS code is here: https://github.com/GunZi200/Memory-Colour/blob/master/test.js

the first thing my program should do is authenticate the user[nothing happens], how come `gamecenter` isn't defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wait for the device ready event before trying to use a plugin

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", authUser, false);

function authUser(){
    gamecenter.auth(successCallback, failureCallback);
}
```

Comment: I did that first yes, but it was as if the deviceready didn't run, I will try again.

Comment: You have to link cordova.js in your index.html, then deviceready will fire

Comment: does fire or doesn't fire?

Comment: All right awesome dude! But there is one more problem. Submitting the score also gives me "gamecenter" not defined. It doesn't need deviceready does it?

Comment: yes, everything should be called after the device ready event